# Vertical alignment of headers and footers with fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, vertical-alignment, fancyhdr

I have seen [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/544075/fancyhdr-vertical-alignment-of-left-header), [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/591979/align-centre-footer-with-left-and-right-footers-with-fancyhdr) and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2440/how-to-vertically-align-headers-footers-in-fancyhdr-package) questions and tried all the solutions in the answers. None of them has worked so far.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=3.00cm, top=0.75cm, bottom=4.50cm, includefoot, includehead, headsep=1.5cm]{geometry}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}

\setlength{\headheight}{150pt}

\lhead{{\textbf{{\Large Meine\\ schöne\\ Schule}}}\\[3ex]\phantom{K}\\[3ex]
    Name:\\[3ex] Datum:\\[-0.5ex]}%
%\chead{}
\rhead{{\textbf{{\Large Arbeitsblatt Mathematik\\ Binomische Formeln}}}\\[3ex] Klasse 8\underline{\phantom{unaclasse}}\\[3ex]
    Seite \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}\\[-0.5ex]}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    
    \section*{Some section title here}
    
    The main body of the section here.

\end{document}
```

I get the space between "Meine", "schöne" and "Schule" inconsistent and, especially annoying, the left and right footer do not vertically align. I have also tried several linebreaks (`\\[...]`) and with them I could get it acceptable, but every time I change something, I have to adjust it all over again.

[image: Result of MWE]

Anything else I could try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inconsistency between the text elements is because a font size change (like `\Large`) only applies the appropriate baseline skip once a paragraph is issued. You don't do that explicitly, only issuing `\\`. The following approach sets the header elements in `tabular`s that helps with this issue and presents things a bit more clearly.

Note the `tabular` alignment is set to `[b]`ottom to assure proper alignment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.5pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{150pt}
\fancyhead[L]{\begin{tabular}[b]{ @{} l }
  \bfseries\Large
  \begin{tabular}[b]{ @{} l }
    Meine \\ schöne \\ Schule
  \end{tabular} \\[3ex]
  Name: \\[3ex]
  Datum:
\end{tabular}
}%
\fancyhead[R]{\begin{tabular}[b]{ r @{} }
  \bfseries\Large
  \begin{tabular}[b]{ r @{} }
    Arbeitsblatt Mathematik \\
    Binomische Formeln
  \end{tabular} \\[3ex]
  Klasse 8 \rule{4em}{.4pt} \\[3ex]
  Seite \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}
\end{tabular}
}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\section*{Some section title here}

The main body of the section here.

\end{document}
```

If you want the two heading components (those in `\bfseries\Large`) to be top-aligned, add a `\strut` on a new line for the `R`ight header:

```
\fancyhead[R]{\begin{tabular}[b]{ r @{} }
  \bfseries\Large
  \begin{tabular}[b]{ r @{} }
    Arbeitsblatt Mathematik \\
    Binomische Formeln \\
    \strut
  \end{tabular} \\[3ex]
  Klasse 8 \rule{4em}{.4pt} \\[3ex]
  Seite \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}
\end{tabular}
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, the second one is the way I wanted it, thank you. I accept the answer, even though I ended up doing it with one tabular with three columns in the center header instead. I also like your use of `\rule` instead of `\underline{\phantom{}}` like I did.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you want your left header to look, but to get equal vertical spacing between the base lines of the entries include a `\strut` for the middle one, or struts for each line for wider spacing.

```
\lhead{{\textbf{{\Large Meine\\ \strut schöne\\ Schule}}}\\[3ex]\phantom{K}\\[3ex]
    Name:\\[3ex] Datum:\\[-0.5ex]}%
```

Comment: That still doesn't look really equally spaced, but it's a lot better. Still there is the problem of the right header: "Arbeitsblatt Mathematik" should be at the same height of "Meine".